# Why does my button text switch to two lines in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to create a very simple email program. It is almost done, but I am having issues with the buttons. Currently, the text overlaps once it passes a certain point.

[image: screenshot]

My code for the buttons is as follows. I am guessing that it perhaps has something to do with the for loop:

```
def mainFun(self):
    """Holds body of thing"""

    #Main Frame
    self.mainFrame = Frame(self)
    self.mainFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = N)

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')#Connect to the Server
    mail.login('someemail.com', 'somepassword')#Login
    mail.list() #Different Gmail Labels
    mail.select("inbox") #Select the Label "inbox"

    result, data = mail.uid('search',None, "ALL")

    uid = data[0] #The data is a list
    uid_list = uid.split() #ids is a space separated string
    latest_email_uid = uid_list[-2] #Get the Latest

    for i in range(1, 11):

        x = -i
        email_number = i
        email_uid = uid_list[x]
        result, data = mail.uid('fetch',email_uid, "(RFC822)") #Fetch the Email's body (RFC822) for the given ID

        raw_email = data[0][1] #Raw data of the Email - needs to be parsed. Includes headers and the body

        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email) #Convert the raw email into string format

        self.newmessage = Button(self.mainFrame,
                                 text = "Email %d:  %s\n" % (email_number, email_message['Subject']),
                                 anchor = W)
        self.newmessage.config(height = 3, width = 100)
        self.newmessage.grid(column = 0, row = i, sticky = NW)
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that some of your data may have extra newlines or whitespace in it? Also, how do you expect the program to behave if that happens? Should the buttons grow taller, or should the data gets chopped off?

Comment: @BryanOakley Perhaps that is the case, but I seriously doubt it as in Gmail there was no newline. But, to eliminate the issue, is there anyway for me to eliminate all newlines in a string in Python (2.7.3)?

Comment: "I doubt it" isn't a good response. It's easy to check, just do a little debugging. To answer your specific question, you can strip all leading and trailing whitespace with `.strip()` (eg: `email_message['Subject'].strip()`). Also, it appears you, yourself are adding a newline to the button, which will result in a blank line below the text.